# Hide/show sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am using this code for my responsive layout mobile sidebar hide/show. I am not an expert in jQuery and just wonder if I can optimize this code with the same functionality.

```
$(function() {
    var a = $("#sidepanelpull");
    var l = $("#sidepanelclose");
    side = $(".qa-sidepanel");
    sideHeight = side.height();

    $(l).hide();

    $(a).on("click", function(b) {
        b.preventDefault();
        side.slideToggle("fast");
        l.fadeToggle("fast");
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Hide Sidebar' ? 'Show Sidebar' : 'Hide Sidebar');
        $(this).toggleClass('sidebar-state');
    });

    $(l).on("click", function(b) {
        b.preventDefault();
        side.slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
        $(a).text($(a).text() == 'Hide Sidebar' ? 'Show Sidebar' : 'Hide Sidebar');
        $(a).toggleClass('sidebar-state');
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var b = $(window).width();
        if (b > 320 && side.is(":hidden")) {
            side.removeAttr("style")
            }
    })
});
```

Little details about the code:

1. `.qa-sidepanel` is a main sidebar div
2. `#sidepanelpull` is a handler when user click it will slide open the `.qa-sidepanel` and also `fadeToggle` `#sidepanelclose` handler ( which is located at the top )
3. `#sidepanelclose` is a text link which will be visible at the top when sidebar is open so user on mobile can close from the top if it is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

style-wise I did some changes, have a look

```
$(function() {

var $window = $(window),
    $a = $("#sidepanelpull"),
    $l = $("#sidepanelclose"),
    $side = $(".qa-sidepanel"),
    sideHeight = $side.height(); // Declared but never used??

$a.on("click", function() {
    $side.slideToggle("fast");
    $l.fadeToggle("fast");
    $a.text( $a.text() == 'Hide Sidebar' ? 'Show Sidebar' : 'Hide Sidebar' );
    $a.toggleClass('sidebar-state');
    return false;
});

$l.hide().on("click", function() {
    $side.slideToggle("fast");
    $l.fadeOut("fast");
    $a.text( $a.text() == 'Hide Sidebar' ? 'Show Sidebar' : 'Hide Sidebar' );
    $a.toggleClass('sidebar-state');
    return false
});

$window.resize(function() {
    var b = $window.width();
    if (b > 320 && $side.is(":hidden")) {
        $side.removeAttr("style")
    }
});

});
```

most notably, you are calling jQuery on object that are already jQuery objects (`$(l)` and so on). every call to `$()` will have its performance overhead. Inmy code the jQuery DOM querying engine is only triggered in the inital variables declaration statement (notice how I grouped `var` declarations with commas).
Even calling `$(this)` has its overhead so it's best to use the cached variable.

Also, it's good practice to start variables names that contain jQuery objects with the dollar sign `$`.

And the `sideHeight` variable is declared but never used?

Since every jQuery method returns the objects it's been called on, you can chain method calls, so I've chained `$l.hide().on()` since `hide()` returns `$l` itself.

Also `removeAttr("style")` should be left as a last resort just in case you don't have better methods to change the element's style.